# How to set a pausing point within an animation

Tags: animate, pause

I am currently working on an animation for a presentation. The animation is generated by LaTeX using the package "animate". It consists of 402 pdf-files. Now what i want is to insert a Pausing point within the animation, lets say i want the animation to play till frame 202 and pause there, so that you have to click on the "play"-Button again for the animation to proceed. An MWE is included here.

I know this is most likely a fairly easy problem, but i'm still a beginner regarding LaTeX.

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}
     \animategraphics[controls, trim=0cm 3cm 0cm 3cm, width=.6 \textwidth]{20}{Bild/forward}{1}{402}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure but seems that last two arguments in `animategraphics` are first and last frame. Then I understand that you can use two `animategraphics` command one from `{1}{100}` and a second one with `{101}{402}`. And if you need it a `\pause` command in between.

Comment: i tried this method, but then latex will generate two animations on two different frames. But nice idea, thanks anyway!

Comment: With the `animateinline` environment you can use `\newframe*` to pause, with `animategraphics` it should be possible with a timeline.txt.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a easy way to do this. Thanks for the tip. i'll search the forum for threads about timeline.txt.

Comment: I would search in the documentation.

Comment: thanks a lot! looks like somebody did the favor for me in the next answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\animategraphics`, a timeline file can be used, as suggested in this [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251522/how-to-set-a-pausing-point-within-an-animation#comment599707_251522).

It would look like

```
::0
::1
...
*::201 %frame from file forward202.pdf; pause here
::202
...
::401 %frame from file forward402.pdf
```

The timeline file could be generated using a spreadsheet application or by in-line code in the tex source:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{multido}
%write timeline file
\newwrite\OutFile%
\immediate\openout\OutFile=timeline.txt%
\multido{\iFrame=0+1}{201}{%
  \immediate\write\OutFile{::\iFrame}%
}%
\immediate\write\OutFile{*::201}%
\multido{\iFrame=202+1}{200}{%
  \immediate\write\OutFile{::\iFrame}%
}%
\immediate\closeout\OutFile%

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}
     \animategraphics[
       controls,
       trim=0cm 3cm 0cm 3cm,
       width=.6\textwidth,
       timeline=timeline.txt
     ]{20}{Bild/forward}{1}{402}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, i'll try this out immediately!

Comment: i tried your code. After running the code, a timeline.txt-file was automatically generated. I then copy-pasted your suggestion (: :0 : :1 ...) into the txt-file. But when i recompiled, the existing txt-file was overwritten with numbers from 1 going to 402 again. Did i do something wrong?  Thanks again.

Comment: @JoeJay : Just run `pdflatex` on the code. The timeline text file will be written on the fly and associated with the animation at once. You will get the ready pdf with the animation. Perhaps another one or two `pdflatex` runs may be necessary, as usual.

Comment: I ran it with pdflatexmk (i'm using TeXShop on Mac OS). The following error appeared on the console:  Package animate Error: timeline file 'timeline.txt' cannot be opened for reading.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I made I typo in the file name. Try the code after the next edit